# How to attach multiple files in mail in Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, mailgun

Previously I was attaching a single pdf file like this to the mail function .

```
Mail::send('emails.questionnairefilled', $data1, function($message) use($htmltosend, $emails){
  $message->to($emails) 
    ->from('admin@ideconnect.com')
    ->subject(Auth::user()->name.', '.Auth::user()->event.'- Questionnaire completed')
    ->attachData(
      $htmltosend,
      Auth::user()->name.'_questionnaire.pdf',
      array('mime'=>'application/pdf', 'Content-Disposition'=>'attachment')
    );
});
```

So if I have to attach more files then do I have to use the `attachData()` function multiple times or there is some other way .

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to make an array of it?

Comment: @RobinR Yes it sayas the ->attach() needs string not array

Answer (score 1):

You can use another email package like [Mailgun](https://github.com/Bogardo/Mailgun) which helps you to send multiple attachment through his "attach" function

Comment: I am using Guzzeler something

Answer (score 1):

```
$path =[];
$path[] = '../path/your/number/one/file';
$path[] = '../path/your/number/two/file';
$data_mail = Mail::send($tmp, array('msg'=>$msg), function($message) use ($path) {
 $message->from('xxx@xxx.com', $_POST['subj'] );
 $message->to($_POST['to'])->subject($_POST['subj'] );
 $size = sizeOf($path); //get the count of number of attachments 

    for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){ 
     $message->attach($path[i]);

    }},true);
```